# Why Hasn't My Time Complexity Improved On This Leet Code Challenge?

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o

I am taking a course on algorithms and big O on Udemy.

I learned that nested loops are bad for performance. I wrote a Leet Code challenge before starting this course, and I wanted to try it again using some things I learned on the course. I was expecting it to be much faster than it was the last time. But it was the same speed. Can someone explain to me where I'm going wrong and why there's no improvement in the performance of this function?

Challenge: function with array and target integer arguments, find the two integers from the array whose sum is the target.

**New code: Time: 212ms**

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let right = nums.length - 1;
    let left = 0;

    // as long as left > nums.lenth - 2
    while (left < nums.length) {
        if (nums[left] + nums[right] === target) {
            return [right, left];
        }
        if (right > left + 1) {
            right--;
        } else {
            left++;
            right = nums.length - 1;
        }
    }
};
```

**Old code: Time: 204ms**

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let ii = 0; ii < nums.length; ii++) {
            if (i !== ii && nums[i] + nums[ii] === target) {
                return [i, ii];
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: Questions like this about optimization are better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: okay thanks @charlietfl

Comment: Big O really becomes a factor as the size of the data set scales.  The timings are meaningless without measuring against varying sizes of data sets.  Eg, O(n^2) roughly means that, say, if you 3x your data set, you're going to have 9x the amount of work involved.  Conversely, the smaller the data set, the more likely the amount of effort will converge regardless of Big O.  Try both sets of code with very large data sets, and see what times you get then...

Answer (score 2):

Big-o is purely theoretical, yet LeetCode's benchmarking is something practical, not to mention that their measurements are highly inaccurate and unreliable, which you can fully ignore. It's just something there without much benefit.

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let numsMap = {};
    for(let index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
        const num = nums[index];
        if(numsMap[target - num] !== undefined) {
            return [numsMap[target - num], index];
        }
        numsMap[num] = index;
    }
    return [];
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We would want to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>). Overall, we would like to avoid anything that might become controversial for interviews.
- There are also other similar [platforms](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-HackerRank-or-LeetCode), which you might have to become familiar with, in case you'd be interviewing with specific companies that would use those platforms.

#### If you are practicing for [contests](https://leetcode.com/contest/)<sup>[1](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf)</sup>:

- Just code as fast as you can, almost everything else is very trivial.
- For [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) questions, brute force algorithms usually get accepted. For interviews, brute force is less desired, especially if the question would be an [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) level.
- For [medium](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Medium) and [hard](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Hard) questions, about 90% of the time, brute force algorithms fail mostly with [Time Limit Exceeded](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/) (TLE) and less with Memory Limit Exceeded (MLE) errors.
- Contestants are ranked based on an algorithm explained [here](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/468851/New-Contest-Rating-Algorithm-(Coming-Soon)).